# VB.NET - Remove a characters from a String

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

I have this string:

```
Dim stringToCleanUp As String = "bon;jour"
Dim characterToRemove As String = ";"
```

I want a function who removes the ';' character like this:

```
Function RemoveCharacter(ByVal stringToCleanUp, ByVal characterToRemove)
...
End Function
```

What would be the function ?

**ANSWER:**

```
Dim cleanString As String = Replace(stringToCleanUp, characterToRemove, "")
```

Great, Thanks!

Comment: Visual Basic and VB.NET are not the same thing (Visual Basic is the non .NET language).

Comment: What in the world is the difference between these two ?

Comment: Consider the next developer who'll have to realize that you've basically wrapped the native `string.replace`. In other words, adding more abstraction when not necessary. Aside: you should mark the answer as the 'accepted' with the green checkmark.

Comment: [Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) came with Visual Studio 6, [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) is a modern .NET language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Function RemoveCharacter(ByVal stringToCleanUp, ByVal characterToRemove)
  ' replace the target with nothing
  ' Replace() returns a new String and does not modify the current one
  Return stringToCleanUp.Replace(characterToRemove, "")
End Function
```

Here's more information about [VB's Replace function](http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace-vbnet)

Answer (score 22):

The `String` class has a [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method that will do that.

```
Dim clean as String
clean = myString.Replace(",", "")
```

Answer (score 5):

The `string` class's `Replace` method can also be used to remove multiple characters from  a string:

```
Dim newstring As String
newstring = oldstring.Replace(",", "").Replace(";", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *string*.replace method

*string*.replace("*character to be removed*", "*character to be replaced with*")

```
Dim strName As String
strName.Replace("[", "")
```