# Remove first 7 chars from every items in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

An example of an item would be:

```
Title1=Hello!
```

I need to remove the first 7 characters to make it:

```
Hello!
```

I have tried this code, but it is not working:

```
ListBox.Items.Item(1).Remove(0, 7)
```

Comment: @putvande: I would guess VB.NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - Remove a characters from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398356/vb-net-remove-a-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: You're trying to remover the first X characters of a string that is not X characters long.  What happens when you try to remove the first X characters from a string that is *longer* than X characters?  Is the result of `Item(1)` mutable?  Does the code work as expected when dealing with a normal string?

Comment: "InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: That's not a problem manipulating a string.  That's a problem manipulating the content of `ListBox.Items`.  You probably need to go through your code and determine why *that* error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each i In ListBox1.Items
        i = (StrReverse(StrReverse(i).Remove(7)))
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim x as Integer

for x = 0 to Listbox1.Items.Count - 1

```
  Listbox1.Items(x) = Listbox1.Items(x).substring(7)
```

next x